# How to get inverse of a comparator in java

Tags: java, generics, heap, priority-queue, comparator

In a method I receive a generic `object E extends Comparable<E>` as an argument. Now i want to create two priority queues.One which uses the `comparator` used by E and other queue which uses the opposite of `comparator` used by E(i.e. if E uses '<' then second queue must use '>=').
Please hep me how to create two such queues.

```
queue2=new PriorityQueue<E>(0,Collections.reverseOrder(e));
```

I am getting the error that `reverseOrder` is not applicable.

please help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at [Collections.reverseOrder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28java.util.Comparator%29).

Comment: queue2=new PriorityQueue<E>(0,Collections.reverseOrder(e));

Comment: I am getting the error that reverseorder is not applicable. please help

Comment: I *never* knew that `Collections.reverseOrder` was there. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your object `E` extends `java.lang.Comparable,` but it is not a `java.util.Comparator`.

Create your first queue w/o a Comparator and you'll get the ordering in your `compareTo` function, then create a `java.util.Comparator` that does the comparison in reverse (just call a.compareTo(b) and then negate the result) and create your second queue with that comparator.

Answer (score 1):

The single argument of [Collections.reverseOrder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28java.util.Comparator%29) is a Comparator and not a Collection. For your code simply use reverseOrder without an argument. You have to use a non-zero inital size, too. The following code will work.

```
queue2=new PriorityQueue<E>(1, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Program depicts how to do it.

I have `StringLengthComparator` which compares based on string length. Using `Collections.reverseOrder` I have created queue which is reverse ordered and another queue which is ordered correctly.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class TestReverseorder {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Comparator<String> comparator = new TestReverseorder().new StringLengthComparator();
    PriorityQueue<String> reverse = new PriorityQueue<String>(10,
            Collections.reverseOrder(comparator));
    PriorityQueue<String> queue = new PriorityQueue<String>(10,comparator);
    queue.add("1");
    queue.add("12");
    queue.add("123");

    reverse.add("1");
    reverse.add("12");
    reverse.add("123");

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(queue.poll());
    }

    while (!reverse.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(reverse.poll());
    }


}

public class StringLengthComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String x, String y) {
        // Assume neither string is null. Real code should
        // probably be more robust
        if (x.length() < y.length()) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (x.length() > y.length()) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

It will print output

```
Normal Order:
1
12
123
Reverse Order:
123
12
1
```